# Has anyone used ECMAScript Proxies yet?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I am trying to get a hang of [**ESx (Harmony?) Proxies**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). I think I know the basics now, but I don't think I'm capable of taking advantage of them.

Has anyone managed to use them for any good? I don't know any library or whatsoever that has done that.

Comment: There are not many uses in the wild because the specification is not stable and the browser support is just not there yet. It has a lot o potential though.

Comment: They're not ES5, FWIW. They will be in ES6.

Comment: @gsnedders: true, I'll edit my post. It is specified as part of ECMAScript Harmony by TC39, and implemented in Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

Proxies are a rather strategic feature that is primarily intended for implementing bindings or advanced library abstractions. Don't worry if you don't see an immediate use case for your own code. In fact, if you did, you should think at least twice before using them -- more often than not they are overkill, and there is a simpler and more efficient way to achieve the same thing.

There are a couple of examples on the original proposal page: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies

Comment: `there is a simpler and more efficient way to achieve the same thing.` can you give some examples?

Answer (score 6):

For more info on proxies, check out [**this article**](http://soft.vub.ac.be/%7Etvcutsem/proxies/) by Assistant Professor Tom Van Cutsem. Together with Google's Mark Miller, Tom actually played a key role in the proposal of proxies for inclusion in a future ECMAScript standard during his work at the [**es-lab**](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/) project.

Further, note that [**DirectProxies.js**](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/source/browse/trunk/src/proxies/DirectProxies.js) has been superseded by the new [**reflect.js**](https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect) shim.

Finally, check out Sindre Sorhus's [**negative-array**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/negative-array) project for an example of simple use case.

---

#### UPDATE:

Today, it's almost 5 years since this question was asked. While they have become part of the ECMAScript 2015 standard (aka ES6) in 2015, many browsers still haven't implemented them :

[image]

If you want to know which browsers support proxies by the time you're reading this answer, [**take a look at CanIUse**](http://caniuse.com/#search=proxies).

Answer (score 4):

Things have evolved a bit! Firefox supports Proxies natively. Using the implementation of [harmony-reflect.js](https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect/blob/master/reflect.js), you can try using proxies according to the proposed specification of [Direct Proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adirect_proxies). This works with current Firefox or [latest Chrome](http://kishorelive.com/2011/12/26/ecmascript-harmony-features-in-google-chrome-canary/).

Possible use case: You have an object that represents a node in a graph containing an `id`, `type`, and arbitrary other user-defined properties. The library drawing this node to the screen wants to save screen-coordinates and similar directly to this node as well. This could possibly overwrite existing properties.

You can now hand over a proxy to the drawing library that catches access to the drawing specific properties of the node. And then, redirect them to an internal namespace property of the node - for example, `drawing` - to separate this data.

This way, all data according to one node can be kept in a single place. There is no need to copy and transform it around for different libraries and maybe later change the same properties in different places.

Comment: DirectProxies.js has been superseded by the new reflect.js  shim. See https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect

Answer (score 0):

Most of the proxy "functionality" can kind of already be implemented in current Javascript. For example, getters and setters can be made as explicit "setXXX" or "getXXX" methods.

The largest up front advantages of proxies I can think of are

1. Taking *existing* behavior that currently resides in evil browser objects and allow it to be implemented with pure Javascript. (Great for browser implementors and for people writing shims)
2. Give you more freedom to change an implementation without breaking the interface (for example, if a property is removed from an object you might put a magic getter in its place to avoid breaking old code).

That said, I'm still curious about what other nice things are possible this new feature :)

Comment: Actually, getters and setters are implemented via `defineProperty` even long before proxies.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to point out that according to this: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies the direct proxies are the latest specification of the ES proxies and its now part of the draft, which means that this gonna be the ES6 standard, once it goes live, as well as the latest gecko engine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy using direct proxies already.

I wrote a little code using the new proxies to make the childnodes inside the DOM be available as properties of their parent node and multi-get, multi-set and function multi-call them, similarly to the query-selectors. This cannot be done dynamically without the proxies, and using proxies made this whole code be less than one KB.

Generally talking proxies makes prototyping and meta-programming be dynamic and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Object fail safe access, without eval, for example:

`someObj.someMethod.someFunction('param1');`

`//--> someObj doesn't exist (with fail safe, no error thrown)`

Answer (score 0):

I used ES6 Proxies together with ES6 Promises in a library in order to implement Lazy Loading:
https://github.com/Daniel-Abrecht/Crazy-Loading

ES6 Proxies are currently working in Firefox 45 and Edge 13, and Chrome 49.